# Cannot get any document in go from mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to make simple query with mongo driver, but there is nothing in result.
InsertOne works fine, FindOne and Find return zero documents. Here is my code:
// my mongo adapter structure

```
package database

import (
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "log"
)

var (
    instance * Client
)

type Client struct {
    Client * mongo.Client
    Ctx context.Context
    Database * mongo.Database
}

func(c * Client) construct() {
    var err error
    c.Ctx = context.TODO()
    c.Client, err = mongo.Connect(c.Ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = c.Client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.Database = c.Client.Database("Foo")
}

func getInstance() * Client{
    if instance == nil {
        instance = new(Client)
        instance.construct()
    }
    return instance
}
```

// CRUD

```
package database

import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "log"
)

type StateRow struct {
    _id primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Id int `bson:"id"`
    State int `bson:"state"`
}

func GetMessageStateByUserID(id int) int {
    client := getInstance()
    stateCollection := client.Database.Collection("MessageStates")
    var result = StateRow{}
    filter := bson.D{{"id", id}}
    err := stateCollection.FindOne(client.Ctx, filter).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return 0
    }
    return result.State
}

func SetMessageStateByUserID(id, state int) error {
    client := getInstance()
    stateCollection := client.Database.Collection("MessagesStates")
    var result = StateRow{}
    filter := bson.D{{"id", id}}
    err := stateCollection.FindOne(client.Ctx, filter).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        _, err2 := stateCollection.InsertOne(client.Ctx, bson.M{"id": id, "state": state})
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Fatal(err2)
            return err2
        }
    } else {
        _, err2 := stateCollection.UpdateOne(client.Ctx, bson.M{"_id": result._id}, bson.M{"state": state})
        if err2 != nil {
            return err2
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have one document for tests, here it is:

```js
{"_id":{"$oid":"6096a52ac811ac303c387f75"},"id":79336406,"state":1}
```

I'm using Windows 10, golang1.16.3, mongodb community.

Upd. The way, I'm calling the GetMessageStateByUserID(id int):

```
/* obj.Message.FromID is not null integer*/
state := database.GetMessageStateByUserID(obj.Message.FromID)
```

Comment: Can you provide details on how you are calling the GetMessageStateByUserID function?

Comment: I ran the code, and everything worked. The document is likely located in the wrong database/collection.

Comment: That's weird because the InsertOne method works when there are no rows in collection, new row inserted, but I cannot query any row from db.

Comment: Where can I see the InsertOne code?

Comment: InsertOne is mongodb driver function, the usage placed in set method, I will edit the question.

Comment: I know that this is a MongoDB driver function. Otherwise, I wouldn't have been here trying to help you out. I have asked for the code where you are invoking the `InsertOne` function. You should have provided all the necessary details before posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the document into the `MessagesStates` collection, and trying to get the data from `MessageStates`.

```golang
// Getting the data from here
client.Database.Collection("MessageStates")
// Saving the data here
client.Database.Collection("MessagesStates")
```